# Python: как работать с POST. Ошибка 405

Tags: python, post

Как работать с данным API (ссылка приведена ниже)?

Как получить токен,если обращение согласно описанию на сайте по [ссылке](https://ofd.ru/developers#v2-auth-token), приводит к ошибке 405:

> {"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method
> 'GET'."}
>
> print (requests.post(url, data={'email': login, 'password':
> password}).text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрос надо отправлять `JSON`

```
import json
import requests

data = json.dumps({'email': login, 'password': password})
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': str(len(data)), 'charset': 'utf-8'}

a = requests.post('https://ofd.ru/api/Authorization/CreateAuthToken', data=data, headers=headers)
print(a)
try:
    resp = a.json()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    resp = None
print(resp)
```

Читайте доки внимательно, так работает

```
>>> r = requests.post('https://ofd.ru/api/Authorization/CreateAuthToken', data=data, headers=headers)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> r.json()
{'AuthToken': 'my_token', 'ExpirationDateUtc': '2017-04-08T09:56:31'}
```

Comment: Вроде бы можно просто `data=data` написать и не указывать заголовки

Comment: А это разве решает проблему? Я вот потестил, у меня всё также 405 error

Comment: Да, ошибка не ушла, по прежнему - 405.

Comment: Ну там целая история с регистрацией, я не могу проверить, пока не заполню форму, а принимать ее не хочет, мне приходит 404

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: Спасибо, работает.